# Are "deal" and "deal in" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, vocabulary, comparison

From Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary:

> She got caught **dealing** drugs in school.
>
> He **deals in** rare books.

I want to express "buying and selling a particular product." It seems that "dealing something" is always related to drugs. I'm not sure. Can I interchange them?

> She got caught **dealing in** drugs in school.
>
> He **deals** rare books.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`Deal in` is a phrasal verb meaning "does business in the area of".

`Deal` means "does business with" or "handles".

So to say "He deals rare books" is not technically wrong as it would be like saying that he regularly does business with rare books (but not necessarily his specialty).

However if you go that far, you might as well say that he deals *in* rare books, which *does* imply that that is his specialty.

You wouldn't say "She got caught dealing in drugs in school" because it is a single occurrence, and "dealing in" implies doing business with regular frequency.

Comment: To me, _deal_ can't be used transitively in this sense, except just barely in the fixed expression _deal drugs_. This may be a BrE/AmE difference.

Comment: @ColinFine Three of Johnson, Five of Donne, Ace of Roosevelt. :P

Answer (score 0):

One of the meanings of the verb *to deal* is *to sell*, so both

> She got caught dealing drugs in school

and

> He deals rare books

look alright.

*To deal in* something may mean either *to work in a particular field* or *to buy and sell something, so*

> He deals in rare books

Looks alright too.

As for buying and selling drugs in particular, the verb to deal may be used without a preposition:

> She got caught dealing in school

or

> She got caught dealing at school,

depending on if she sells drugs by herself, being there (at), or via some inside peddlers (in).

[(see: deal, 7)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deal)